# How can I refresh parent page when child page closed in window application ?

Tags: forms

I have one Parent form. In that when I open a child form to update label text it is working but when I close child form, the parent form is not updating the label text. How can I refresh parent page when child page closed?

Answer (score 0):

Write an event handler for the FormClosed event of the child window that refreshes the parent window.

Comment: Home hm = new Home();
            hm.Refresh();
            this.Close();  I have put this code but it is not working . when the child form is closed label value is not update because the parent form is not refresh or reload. how can i solve this ?

Comment: oh i get you now and i write Home hm = new Home(); hm.Refresh(); this.Close(); this code on form closed event but still it is not working

Comment: Why do you create a new Home ? Your parent window should already exist when the child window opens. Assuming the parent window is called hm, simply put hm.refresh() in the child window's FormClosed event handler.

Comment: thank you sir for your resonance. I tried as a said but its not working.this is my code .. private void Labelrename_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            hm.Refresh();
           // this.Close();
          
        }

Comment: Did you bind your code to the FormClosed event ? In the Properties of your child window, click on the lightning icon to display the events, find FormClosed, double-click on it. This creates a new event handler in which you can refresh the parent form.

Comment: No sir and which code should i bind there ? I have create a form closed event as you said and in that i write hm.refresh();This is my code 
        private void Labelrename_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
          
            hm.Refresh();
           
          
        }  please check it and give me solution as soon as possible.thank you

Comment: Here is [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry to say but it is not helpful for me

Comment: yes but it is not reload or refresh my home page at closing of label rename page.. can u give me batter solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I believe this is all I can do. I think you should seek real-life tuition, it will be difficult to help you through the Internet.